# Read AICC Server response in cross domain implementation

Tags: xss

I am currently trying to develop a web activity that a client would like to track via their Learning Management System.  Their LMS uses the AICC standard (HACP binding), and they keep the actual learning objects on a separate content repository.

Right now I'm struggling with the types of communication between the LMS and the "course" given that they sit on two different servers.  I'm able to retreive the **sessionId** and the **aicc_url** from the URL string when the course launches, and I can successfully post values to the **aicc_url** on the LMS.

The difficulty is that I can not read and parse the return response from the LMS (which is formatted as plain text).  AICC stipulates that the course start with posting a "getParam" command to the aicc_url with the session id in order to retrieve information like completion status, bookmarking information from previous sessions, user ID information, etc, all of which I need.

I have tried three different approaches so far:

**1 -** I started with using jQuery (1.7) and AJAX, which is how I would typically go about a same-server implementation.  This returned a "no transport" error on the XMLHttpRequest.  After some forum reading, I tried making sure that the ajax call's crossdomain property was set to true, as well as a recommendation to insert **$.support.cors = true** above the ajax call, neither of which helped.

**2 & 3 -** I tried using an oldschool frameset with a form in a bottom frame which would submit and refresh with the returned text from the LMS and then reading that via javascript; and then a variation upon that using an iFrame as a target of an actual form with an onload handler to read and parse the contents.  Both of these approaches worked in a same-server environment, but fail in the cross-domain environment.

I'm told that all the other courses running off the content repository bookmark as well as track completion, so obviously it is possible to read the return values from the LMS somehow; AICC is pitched frequently as working in cross-server scenarios, so I'm thinking there must be a frequently-used method to doing this in the AICC structure that I am overlooking.  My forum searches so far haven't turned up anything that's gotten me much further, so if anyone has any experience in cross-domain AICC implementations I could certainly use recommendations!

The only idea I have left is to try setting up a PHP "relay" form on the same server as the course, and having the front-end page send values to that, and using the PHP to submit those to the LMS, and relay the return text from the LMS to the front-end iframe or ajax call so that it would be perceived as being within the same domain.... I'm not sure if there's a way to solve the issue without going server-side.  It seems likely there must be a common solution to this within AICC.

Thanks in advance!

***Edits and updates:***
For anyone encountering similar problems, I found a few resources that may help explain the problem as well as some alternate solutions.

The first is specific to Plateau, a big player in the LMS industry that was acquired by Successfactors.  It's some documentation that provide on setting up a proxy to handle cross-domain content:
http://content.plateausystems.com/ContentIntegration/content/support_files/Cross-domain_Proxlet_Installation.pdf

The second I found was a slide presentation from Successfactors that highlights the challenge of cross-domain content, and illustrates so back-end ideas for resolving it; including the use of reverse proxies.  The relevant parts start around slide 21-22 (page 11 in the PDF).
http://www.successfactors.com/static/docs/successconnect/sf/successfactors-content-integration-turley.pdf

Hope that helps anyone else out there trying to resolve the same issues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer in this post may lead you in the right direction:

[Best Practice: Legitimate Cross-Site Scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52646/best-practice-legitimate-cross-site-scripting?rq=1)

I think you are on the right track with setting up a PHP "relay."  I think this is similar to choice #1 in the answer from the other post and seems to make most sense with what you described in your question.

Comment: Thanks -- from additional information I'm reading, I think you may be right; it sounds like even if I could get approval from the appropriate parties to add HTTP headers to the response from the server and get the jQuery / aJax to work, it still wouldn't work on mobile browsers (which sound like they block **all** cross-domain POSTs) -- and the idea is eventually this could be accessed from tablet devices, so the server-side solution may be the best bet.  As long as it works!